# Issue with views on button click

Tags: django, image, twitter-bootstrap, upload, carousel

I am trying to make a carousel that you can upload pictures to.  However, when I click on the upload button, It switches to another page, rather than giving me just the upload selection panel as Intended.  Can anyone tell me why this might be?

Views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login
from webportal.views.authentication import LoginForm
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response
from django.template import RequestContext
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse
from django.conf import settings
from webportal.forms.forms import DocumentForm
from webportal.models import Document
is_server = True
def list(request):
    # Handle file upload
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = DocumentForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            newdoc = Document(docfile = request.FILES['docfile'])
            newdoc.save()

            # Redirect to the document list after POST
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('webportal.views.list'))
    else:
        form = DocumentForm() # A empty, unbound form

    # Load documents for the list page
    documents = Document.objects.all()
    #documents=DocumentForm().
    # Render list page with the documents and the form
    return render_to_response(
        'webportal/carousel.html',
        {'documents': documents, 'form': form,},
        context_instance=RequestContext(request)
    )
```

Carousel.html

```
{% load staticfiles %}
{% load filename %}
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
                <!-- Indicators -->
                <ol class="carousel-indicators">
                    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
                    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
                    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
                </ol>
                <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
                    {% for document in documents %}
 <div class="item {% if forloop.first %} active {% endif %}"> 
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col">
        <img src = "{{STATIC_URL}}img" >
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  {% endfor %}
                </div>
                <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
                    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
                </a>
                <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
                    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
                </a>
            </div>
            <!-- /.carousel -->
        </div>
    </div>
<form action="{% url 'webportal:list' %}" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            {% csrf_token %}
            <p>{{ form.non_field_errors }}</p>
            <p>{{ form.docfile.label_tag }} {{ form.docfile.help_text }}</p>
            <p>
                {{ form.docfile.errors }}
                {{ form.docfile }}
            </p>
            <p><input type="submit" value="Upload" /></p>
        </form>
</div>
```

Forms:

```
class DocumentForm(forms.Form):
    docfile = forms.ImageField(label='Select a file', help_text='max. 42 megabytes')
```

Models:

```
class Document(models.Model):
    docfile = models.ImageField(upload_to='webportal/static/img/')
```

Comment: Can you post your form and model too?

Comment: Done. Models and forms added

Comment: I am unsure what you are trying to do, but this line `<form action="{% url 'webportal:list' %}" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">` will redirect you to whatever the `action` value is when the submit (upload) button is clicked. Are you wanting to upload a photo and see it show in the carousel straight away?

Comment: yes.  That is exactly it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what you mean by "just the upload selection panel as Intended".

Firstly, I see a problem by you returning an empty form if the submitted form is invalid, you should rather return the existing form and show the errors.

Your form, upon clicking the upload button will send a POST request to your server and your view generates a whole new HTML page as a response. HTTP is stateless, meaning that whatever your browser showed before is basically no longer of relevance. So naturally you will see a new page.